# Search for Views in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, view, laravel-blade

I am working on a site where I have a map for each city I need e.g 'London.blade.php', 'Paris.blade.php'.
I a trying to implement a search bar on the site and I need it to return the views(blade.php pages) as the results, not contents of the views.
e.g `where('views', 'LIKE', "%$search_query%")`.Is this actually possible as the views are not stored in the database, if so does anyone know how to go about this?

Comment: You could write a recursive function to read all the foo.blade.php filenames present in /resources/views and subfolders, and push them into an array.

Comment: Hi, I am not too familiar with PHP so I am a bit lost, 'foo.blade.php'?... Are there any examples online you could point me to please? @IarsAnders

Comment: have a look at this on how you can return all the views in laravel - http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/show-all-available-views

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general-purpose function to list any file with the extension you specify, in this case, `.blade.php`. It starts searching at `$path` and then recursively searches any sub-directories it finds.

```
function findFileExtension_r($extension, $path, &$names = array()){
    $files = array_diff(scandir($path), array('..', '.'));
    foreach($files as $f){

        $abs_path = $path.'/'.$f;

        if(is_dir($abs_path)){ //directory, recurse

            findFileExtension_r($extension, $abs_path, $names);

        } else {  //file, test if the name ends with $extension
            $ext_length = strlen($extension);
            if(substr($f, -$ext_length) === $extension){
                $names[] = $f;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
//set up some values
$find = '.blade.php';
$path = 'path/to/laravel/resources/views';
//$blade_templates = array(); //can be initialized, or named in the function call below.

//call function
findFileExtension_r($find, $path, $blade_templates);

//output
echo '<h2>Results</h2><pre>' . print_r($blade_templates, true) . '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually store your blade templates in the database and query them via SQL: https://github.com/delatbabel/viewpages

Answer (score 0):

If the views are not stored in the db, you'll have to point to the view in the routes and you can use a dynamic route.

```
Route::get('/{slug}', array('as' => 'page.show', 'uses' => 'PageController@show'));
```

The show function:

```
public function show()
{
    $slug = input::get('location');
    $page = page::whereSlug($slug)->get();
    return View::make('pages')->with('page', $page);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I seem to be doing something wrong as it throws an error,   "Missing required parameters for [Route: page.show] [URI: countries/{canada}]. (View:/Users/ccg/testsite/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php)"....this is what I have for the route    "Route::get('countries/{canada}', array('as' => 'page.show', 'uses' => 'PageController@show'));"  and for the search box I have <form action="{{ URL::action('PageController@show') }}" method="get"> <input type="text" name="location" placeholder="Search!" </form>...I just want to be able to type the country name(only) into the search box. @Piya Desai

Comment: Wait a min. Why is it '{canada}' ? What does that folder contain ?

Comment: I have a main view folder called "countries", within it I have subfolders of each country that I need e.g Canada, within the Canada folder, I have an index.blade.php file as well as other cities.... It is throws the same error when I use "Route::get('/{slug}'"....Missing required parameters for [Route: page.show] [URI: {slug}]...I also tried changing it to Route::get('/slug', array('as' => 'page.show', 'uses' => 'PageController@show')); but it throws the error "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\page' not found"

Comment: You cannot use '/slug'. It might be quite a lot of pages. Why don't you try storing the pages in the database ? You can retrieve and display.